# Locking Cells that have formulas using EPPlus

Tags: epplus

I want to lock a cell that has a value calculated by a formula using EPSPlus.

So if a cell used in the formula is changed the cell value will change accordingly however the cell cannot be edited directly, is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just protect the worksheet and lock the required cell, this should not affect the formulas

```
worksheet.Protection.IsProtected = true;
worksheet.Cells["A1:B1"].Style.Locked = true;
```